# What are the differences between the different platform version?

Tags: version-differences, the-walking-dead-season-one

What are the differences (if any) between the Walking Dead for different platforms?

The main concern I had is save data carrying over from season 1 to 2, and since season 2 hasn't been released on Vita, that causes you to have to wait. Are there any other differences besides that?

Comment: The first game didn't have any differences, so I would expect this one to be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have basically answered my own questions by playing it.  The versions are all practically identical, besides graphics.

The only difference, is release on systems besides PC is delayed more than PC. SO once the PC version releases, it takes awhile for the other versions to get released.